# Fetch URL from word list on openRefine

Tags: openrefine

I have a list of organisations in Column 1 (string with spaces, e.g. United Nations) and want to populate a second column with the associated URLs (e.g. www.un.org/), using the column 1 values as a search string. The geocoding procedure is rather straightforward (http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/OpenRefine_Tutorial#Geocoding_names_and_addresses), so I wonder if there is a way to perform this task using google search or other web service. It would be a hit and miss approach, but it beats manual editing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer a so broad question without specific examples. But of course, we can use Open Refine to enrich data using a ton of APIs or by doing web scraping. And the procedure is almost always the same: rebuild URLs, "add a column by fetching urls", and then parsing the resulting column of HTML, XML or JSON files.

Here is an example on how to call the [Wikipedia search API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=britney%20spears&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml) from a list of names.

[image: screencast]

Rebuild URLs is quite simple :

```
"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="

+ value.escape('url')

+ "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml"
```

What, for `value='United Nations'`, would give this :

[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=united+nations&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=united%20nations&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml)

The XML content can then be parsed to extract the items you need. For example, to get the description of the Wikipedia page :

```
value.parseHtml().select('Description').htmlText()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly with wikipedia's API or, as I had menrioned before, with Google maps. However, I don't get it to work with the google search one.

Comment: I tried (and failed): "http://www.google.com/uds?action=opensearch&search=" + value.escape('url') + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml".
I guess the alternative would be a CSE (Custom Search Engine) and corresponding API key and search engine ID. However, I wouldn't know how to add these to the code. I tried (and failed) this: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY_HERE&cx=CX_HERE?action=opensearch&search=United+Nations&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: the method I explained works with a Wikipedia URL. For another service, use another URL. "Opensearch" or "xml" make no sense in a search on google.com. And anyway, you will not be able to scrape Google. Google is the biggest scraper in the world and does not allow anyone to do the same with it. You need to use some Google APIs.